# Trying to clean up my jquery/javascript and think more functionally

Tags: jquery

I'm new and I'm trying to think more functionally and clean up my code-make it drier...I've tried to use this with hover and it won't work.  I know I'm missing out on something simple and easier, but...thanks in advance for help.

```
$('#phone').on({
        mouseenter: function() {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/PhoneBlue.png')},
        mouseleave: function() {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/Phone4.png')}});

  $('#email').on({
        mouseenter: function() {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/EmailBlue.png')},
        mouseleave: function() {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/Email4.png')}});

  $('#live-chat').on({
        mouseenter: function() {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/ChatBoxBlue.png')},
        mouseleave: function() {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/ChatBox4.png')}});
```

Comment: Did you try `mouseover` instead of `mouseenter`? And `mouseout` instead of `mouseleave`?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If hover didn't work, it was probably because your syntax was wrong. What's the question, exactly?

Comment: I gave an answer but I realized I may have misunderstood the question, can you refine it a bit so it's more obvious what your goal is?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ,
but remember phone,email and live-chat must be id of the image tag

```
$('#phone').hover(
    function () {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/EmailBlue.png');},
    function () {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/Phone4.png');}
);


$('#email').hover(
    function () {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/EmailBlue.png');},
    function () {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/Email4.png');}
);


$('#live-chat').hover(
    function () {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/ChatBoxBlue.png');},
    function () {$(this).attr('src','../web-marketing/images/ChatBox4.png');}
);
```